# How do I open / extract files from a .b1 archive?

Tags: archiving

I have downloaded an archive and it has a `.b1` extension.

How can I open this archive and extract its contents?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.b1` file format is typically associated with files downloaded from the 4Shared file hosting service. Currently, there is only one tool capable of  operating with `.b1` files, the [B1 Free Archiver](http://b1.org/).

---

It is **not an open source** software, despite the name, and despite what they state on the website:

> Open source: We're happy to share b1 with everyone, so all code is open. You can download sources of all b1 tools and libraries here. Feel free to use them in any of your products or services.

The only part of the program which is free/libre software, is called the *B1 Pack Project*.

The website describes it as follows:

> B1 Pack is an open-source software project that produces a cross-platform command-line tool and a Java library for creating and extracting file archives in the B1 archive format.

So, to quote from [this forum thread](http://trisquel.info/en/forum/b1-free-archiver):

> Basically the B1 archive format, and the corresponding CLI tools are free/libre software, but the GUI, since there is no source code access/license statement for it, making it instantly proprietary.

So the only open-source option is the [B1 Pack Project](http://dev.b1.org/), it has a [CLI tool](http://dev.b1.org/tool-usage.html).